# authenticate using kerberos with curl

Tags: authentication, curl

So basically I have a web application in which I have implemented kerberos authentication.

I can authenticate and get the response from the web application using curl when I'm on my account.

The problem starts when I'm on a linux machine (using putty). When I'm from the machine and try authenticating against the web application, after the application returns header with WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate the command just stops.

Now I'm assuming it is because on the machine I'm not a user in the active directory, but a computer or something else as such.

So I tried doing kinit with my username and password, and after the token was created successfully, It still gets stuck. I'm guessing because he doesn't know that I want him to use the token I just created.

So my question is : How do I get the curl to work even though I'm on a linux machine? or How can I use the token I created to authenticate even though I'm not on the user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you run your web app on a Windows box? If yes, please make it explicit.

Comment: What kind of Kerberos back-end do you use? Active Directory of MIT Kerberos? Please make it explicit because it makes **A LOT** of difference.

Comment: Assuming that you use cURL on Windows, do you know what kind of Kerberos protocol was built-in at compile time? SSPI *(the Microsoft way)* or GSSAPI *(the Linux/Java way)*? Because it makes **A LOT** of difference.

Comment: I'm running my Web app on Linux, active directory of MIT kerberos, GSSAPI.

Comment: *"active directory of MIT kerberos"* -- what do you mean? Which kind of KDC does your `/etc/krb5.conf` point to, a Windows Server box with Microsoft Active Directory, or a Linux box with MIT Kerberos?

Comment: A Windows server with Microsoft active directory.